# Automated Detection of "Spikes" in Object Contours Using Contour Points and Binary Masks OpenCV cv2

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, mask

I'm currently working on a project where I have the contour points of a binary mask representing a specific object. My goal is to automatically detect if the object has a protruding "spike." I've attached three images for reference, where one exhibits a prominent spike, another a smaller one, and the third has no spikes.

Given the contour points, the original image, and the mask of the objects, I'm seeking advice on an algorithm or method to efficiently identify the presence of spikes in the object contours.

Any insights, code snippets, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape